Solving set of Gaussian integrals, integrating over an implicitly defined function that depends on the values of the integrals
I have the following NExpectations and the Implicit Function
phi[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, mc_?NumericQ, ms_?NumericQ] := 
 FindRoot[-((1 - Lambda)*mc + Sqrt[alpha]*x)*
      Sin[phi] + ((1 - Lambda)*ms + Sqrt[alpha]*y)*Cos[phi] - 
     alpha*(C2*Sin[phi]*Sin[phi] - S1*Cos[phi]*Cos[phi] + (C1 - S2)*Cos[phi]*Sin[phi]), 
     {phi, 3.1}][[1]][[2]]

fmc[mc_] := 
  mc - NExpectation[
    Cos[phi[x, y, mc, ms]], {x, y} \[Distributed] 
     MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, Q]];

fms[ms_] := 
  ms - NExpectation[
    Sin[phi[x, y, mc, ms]], {x, y} \[Distributed] 
     MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, Q]];

The coefficients used are as follows
Q1 = 0.9;
Q2 = .5;
Q3 = 0.5;
Q = {{Q1, Q3}, {Q3, Q2}};
Lambda = 0.6;
C1 = 0.1;
C2 = 0.1;
S1 = 0.1;
S2 = 0.1;
alpha = 0.001;

I need the values of $m_s, m_c$, and the final $phi$ function. The Matrix $Q,$ and $C_1. S_1, C_2, S_2, Lambda,~ alpha$ are constants. The equations need to be solved simultaneously, I am using the following code to converge to a solution.
FindRoot[{fmc[mc], fms[ms]}, {{mc, 0.5}, {ms, 0.5}}]

The following are my questions :-

Running the last code, continuous forever. Is this approach correct? Will this converge to a simultaneous solution? As in, since $phi$ needs to be updated after every iteration.
If it correct, is there a way to increase the speed of this computation. (As eventually the constants need to be replaced with more integrals. )

I am very new to both Mathematica and Numerically solving equations involving Gaussian integrals. Thank you very much, any help is deeply appreciated.

As suggested by @user64494, the following changes at least converges, but throws errors,
FindRoot[{fmc[mc, ms], fms[mc, ms]}, {{mc, 0.5}, {ms, 0.5}}] 
NExpectation::input: Invalid input.
NExpectation::input: Invalid input.
{mc -> -0.835723, ms -> -0.54821}

The converged solution is fairly accurate,
ms - NExpectation[Sin[phi[x, y, mc, ms]], {x, y} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, Q]] /. {mc -> -0.835723, ms -> -0.54821} 

results in 9.39736*10^-8.
The function
Plot3D[phi[x, y, -0.83, -0.54], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]



Executing your code , I obtain several errors, e.g. "NExpectation::input: Invalid input".

Sorry, I have added the coefficient values, used for the implicit function.

Again errors "NExpectation::input: Invalid input" and a warning "NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small" and spinning.

@user64494, it doesn't give the error "NExpectation::input: Invalid input" for me, but yes, the computation never ends, it keeps going. I have tried running it iteration wise manually, it takes a while after the first three iterations. I don't know why this might be the case. My guess is the function doesn't behave well, which causes the NIntegration to evaluate slowly. Do you have any ways to debug what might be the reason? Thanks very much for your comment.

As far as I understand, it should be fmc[mc_,ms_] instead of fmc[mc_]. Even then fmc[1, 1] produces 1.69998 and a warning and an error.

@user64494, I got the solution after a 30 minutes of running FindRoot...,
{mc -> -0.835723, ms -> -0.54821}, which is a possible solution. This is even though there is an initial error of NExpectation::input: Invalid input.

Unfortunately, mc - NExpectation[    Cos[phi[x, y, mc, ms]], {x, y} \[Distributed]      MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, Q]] /. {mc -> -0.835723,    ms -> -0.54821} results in -0.00687833 and three errors/warnings.

In fact, fmc[mc]==0 coincides with fms[ms]==0 in your notations.

@user64494, it does? But, function over which they integrate is different, cos & sin?

You are right concerning the equations: the ones do differ.. Sorry for the trouble

@user64494, thanks for clearing this up, despite of the error, the solution seems correct(?) This discussion has been pretty helpful. Any reason why the error NExpectation::input: Invalid input shows up, even though the solution is correct?

Don't know it. No idea.

@user64494, Alright, thank you very much. Do you think this can be sped up anyway?

Sorry, your statement "The converged solution is fairly accurate..." does not correspond to reality Executing your code on a fresh kernel, I obtain -0.00194724  a warning and two error messages. One of those is "NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times.

The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained -0.546263 and 0.00005486831109143135` for the integral and error estimates."

@user64494, my sincerest apologies, I was running a different system in my notebook kernel, I have made the edit above. The error, NExpectation :Invalidinput... still persists though. Sorry for the inconvenience.
